# Can alivio fd (m4000 or m3100) handle 44/32/22 crankset?

Tags: crankset, shifting, derailleur-front

Bought a m3100 alivio groupset together with a fc mt210 44/32/22 crankset. Will a m3100 side swing fd   or a m4000 top swing be able to handle a 44/32/22 crankset? I have read on the shimano website and product descriptions that the maximum teeth for these fd's is only 40t. If so, is it possible to overcome this with adjustments with the fd set up and tuning?

If these can't handle such teeth, what fd should I buy?

Thank you in advance for the answers. Ride safe everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you can return the front derailleur, it would be the easiest. Maybe the M3100 can handle your crankset, as shimano is known to be conservative in their specs, but it might not be the best (the cage can too short for example).

Your crankset is closer to the trekking ones, so there is certainly a front derailleur in this product range (FD-Txxxx) that matches your crankset better.

Comment: But is there a work around for this? Like adjusting the height of the fd or adjusting the high low screws? Or it will simply not work at all with a 44t? I'm trying to go for the cheapest solution or cost free solution since I already have the fd with me. Thanks

Comment: @Anonymousnewbee There's no harm in going ahead and installing the FD you have. The normal installation process includes placing the FD cage a certain distance from the large chainring teeth (looking at it sideways) and aligning the cage edge with the large chainring (looking down from above). I believe the specs on maximum gear tooth count difference and maximum number of teeth on the largest gear follow from the fact that the FD cage moves not only side to side but also up and down, tracking the chain position from chainring to chainring. It should be pretty clear if yours works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased (new old stock?) a Shimano LX M580 3x9 Front Derailleur, 44 tooth max chainring size, 22t max capacity, so works well for 44/32/22 crankset.  There are older models out there, whether in stores or on places like ebay.